# Integration of Open ERP & Django to configure openerp instances 

Tags: django, django-forms, django-templates, odoo

I am new to Django.

I'm developing a Django application where user will enter UserName & DatabaseName (new Database to be generated by openerp)

So once User submits the username & dbname, it will call Open ERP API to create new database and setup new username/password as per specified in Django App.

Once new DB is configured, openerp API should also notify the user by email with the link (web client) to access his new account of openerp...

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: I don't completely understand what are you tring to achieve. Are you tring to create a database or export the data as the title says?

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can create databases via the XLM-RPC (I may be wrong), but you could just use Django to create a new postgres database with the openerp user as owner, and insert a default user into the user table. You could send an email from Django when its all set up.

Also have a look at these scripts which help administer openerp instances https://code.launchpad.net/~clearcorp/openerp-ccorp-scripts